# How can i login to Firebase using the details of email authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

How can i use the details of the firebase email authentication sign in instead of me using the email and password i added myself..

```
   private void loginToFirebase() {
    String email = getString(R.string.firebase_email);
    String password = getString(R.string.firebase_password);
    // Authenticate with Firebase and subscribe to updates
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                subscribeToUpdates();
                Log.d(TAG, "firebase auth success");
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "firebase auth failed");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: If you are going to hardcode Id and password and loginto firebase everytime like this, what is the need to add login in your app in the first place ? You can let your users directly to use the app without login right ?

Answer (score 1):

Like the Firebase documentation said :

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
// User is signed in
} else {
// No user is signed in
}
```

[Here is the Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users)

Comment: After that, you will be able to access all the info of the user from Firebase.Auth in the user variable properties.